# How to call setattr before getattr in nested calling

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to create a nested structure and can be freely edited.

For example, for a `e = Example()`, I can set `e.a.b.c = 1` and it will create `a = Example(), b = Example()` for me, but if I access something does not exists like `e.a.b.d`, it should throw an `AttributeError`.

I found that, before calling `__setattr__`, `__getattr__` is first called to get `e.a.b`. One workaround is to create and return an `Example` upon `AttributeError`, but it works as a `defaultdict` and won't raise exception when getting attributes.

```py
class Example:
    def get(self, name: str, default: Optional[Any] = None) -> Any:
        @wraps(self.get)
        def get(self, name):
            if '.' in name:
                name, rest = name.split('.', 1)
                return getattr(self[name], rest)
            elif getattr(self, "_frozen", False):
                try:
                    return super().__getattribute__(name)
                except AttributeError:
                    super().__setattr__(name, Example())
                    return self[name]
            return super().__getattribute__(name)

        if default is not None:
            try:
                return get(self, name)
            except AttributeError:
                return default
        return get(self, name)

    __getitem__ = get
    __getattr__ = get

    def set(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        if '.' in name:
            name, rest = name.split(self.delimiter, 1)
            if not hasattr(self, name):
                setattr(self, name, Example())
            setattr(self[name], rest, value)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)

    __setitem__ = set
    __setattr__ = set
```

Comment: "I can set `e.a.b.c = 1` and it will create `a = Example()`, `b = Example()` for me, but if I access something does not exists like `e.a.b.d`, it should throw an AttributeError." Yeah, that's not possible. You can either automatically create the missing attributes or throw an error, but not both.

Comment: Is it possible to trace the source of function call?

Comment: Sometimes, with [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack). But I strongly advise against it. Rather than trying to work around such a fundamental part of python, accept that you're trying to do something weird and reconsider your design.

Comment: Actually I have tried `inspect.stack`... but it only has `get` stack.

Comment: This is used for a [config system](https://github.com/ZhiyuanChen/CHANfiG), and I worry if some error messages like `except str but got Example() object` caused by a typo would confuse users.